# OWD and Profile Security Settings

Tags: security, sharing-rule, field-level-security, owd, record-access-level

I am facing an issue.

2 Custom objects Job(master) and Candidate (child).

- Job - parent (OWD private) (Custom Profile permission  - Read permission only)
- Candidate - Child (OWD Controlled by parent) (Custom Profile permissions - create, read and edit permissions)
  No sharing rule applied.

Master-detail field "Job"

Sharing Setting: Read Only: Allows users with at least Read access to the Master record to create, edit, or delete related Detail records.

By default Candidate should inherit sharing settings of Job object. But even after trying out everything, I am able to create, read and edit candidate records.

Hope the images help:

Object permission for team lead profile job object:
[image: Object permission for team lead profile job object]

Object permission for team lead profile candidate object:
[image: Object permission for team lead profile candidate object]

OWD for both job and candidate object:
[image: OWD for both job and candidate object]

Sharing rule for job object:
[image: Sharing rule for job object]

I understand due to read only permission I am able to create, read and edit on child object but I don't understand how does it inherit sharing settings from master?

Do I make sense?

Comment: Sharing (without any sharing rules) will depend on ownership. Does your master (Job) belong to your User or to someone else's User? If it belongs to you, naturally you have write sharing for it and all children (candidates), with CRUD per permissions. If it belongs to someone else behaviour should change for sharing. However, since you have set that specific flag on the master detail lookup field, I believe this essentially overrides the sharing to promote it from read to write. You should check the documentation.

Comment: Also check this [article](https://architect.salesforce.com/fundamentals/platform-sharing-architecture).